# Prooftrees logic tree preamble for an example

Tags: tikz-trees, trees, logic, proof-package

The following example is out of the documentation of `prooftrees` (I suppose that an updated version of TeX Live is needed to make use of that package).
The problem is that the documentation's `.tex` file has a gigantic preamble. What I need is a minimal example of the preamble to run that code so that I can start to experiment with the package:

```
\begin{codcoeden}*[label=ptdefaults]{\pkg{prooftrees}: default settings}
\begin{prooftree}
{
to prove={\{P \vee (Q \vee \lnot R), P \lif \lnot R, Q \lif \lnot R\} \sststile{}{} \lnot R}
}
[P \vee (Q \vee \lnot R),  just=Ass, checked
[P \lif \lnot R,  just=Ass, checked
  [Q \lif \lnot R,  just=Ass, checked, name=last premise
    [\lnot\lnot R, just={$\lnot$ Conc}, name=not conc
      [P,  just={$\vee$ Elim:!uuuu}
        [\lnot P, close={:!u,!c}]
        [\lnot R,  close={:not conc,!c}, just={$\lif$ Elim:!uuuu}]]
      [Q \vee \lnot R
        [Q, move by=1
          [\lnot Q, close={:!u,!c}]
          [\lnot R,  close={:not conc,!c}, just={$\lif$ Elim:last premise}]]
        [\lnot R, close={:not conc,!c}, move by=1, just={$\vee$ Elim:!u}]]]]]]
\end{prooftree}
\end{codcoeden}
```

The tree looks like this in the end:

[image]

Comment: To use that code to produce that tree, you only need to load `prooftrees` in the preamble and define any non-standard maths commands e.g. `\lif` which you want to use. If you want to display the code and tree side-by-side in a box just like that, that's a different matter. It is not clear to me which of these you are trying to do.

Comment: I just wanted to do the tree. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To typeset the tree itself, you just need to load `prooftrees` in the preamble and define any special symbols required by the particular content of the tree. In this case `\lif` is non-standard and we need the `turnstile` package for the turnstile.

So,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{prooftrees,turnstile}
\newcommand*{\lif}{\ensuremath{\mathbin{\rightarrow}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
{
to prove={\{P \vee (Q \vee \lnot R), P \lif \lnot R, Q \lif \lnot R\} \sststile{}{} \lnot R}
}
[P \vee (Q \vee \lnot R),  just=Ass, checked
[P \lif \lnot R,  just=Ass, checked
  [Q \lif \lnot R,  just=Ass, checked, name=last premise
    [\lnot\lnot R, just={$\lnot$ Conc}, name=not conc
      [P,  just={$\vee$ Elim:!uuuu}
        [\lnot P, close={:!u,!c}]
        [\lnot R,  close={:not conc,!c}, just={$\lif$ Elim:!uuuu}]]
      [Q \vee \lnot R
        [Q, move by=1
          [\lnot Q, close={:!u,!c}]
          [\lnot R,  close={:not conc,!c}, just={$\lif$ Elim:last premise}]]
        [\lnot R, close={:not conc,!c}, move by=1, just={$\vee$ Elim:!u}]]]]]]
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

[image: prooftree]